# SQLAlchemy ORM LEFT OUTER JOIN with parentheses

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to translate the following raw sql into SQLAlchemy ORM

Raw SQL:

```
objects = request.db.execute("select user_login.userlogin_id, user_friend.status,"\
    " user_login.email, user_info.fname, user_info.lname"\
    " from user_login "\
    " LEFT OUTER JOIN user_info on "\
    " user_info.userlogin_id = user_login.userlogin_id "\
    " LEFT OUTER JOIN user_friend on "\
    " (user_info.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_from_userlogin_id or"\
    " user_info.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_to_userlogin_id )"\
    " where email='%s' " %request.POST['q'])
```

SQLAlchemy version:

```
objects = request.db.query(UserLogin.email, UserLogin.userlogin_id, UserInfo.fname, 
UserInfo.lname, UserFriend.status)\
.outerjoin(UserInfo, UserLogin.userlogin_id == UserInfo.userlogin_id)\
.outerjoin(UserFriend, 
or_(UserLogin.userlogin_id == UserFriend.send_from_userlogin_id \
,UserLogin.userlogin_id == UserFriend.send_to_userlogin_id) )\
.filter(UserLogin.email==request.POST['q'])
```

I took a look at the log and it is the following which looks a bit strange to me, as it doesn't have any parentheses:

```
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-4] SELECT user_login.email AS 
user_login_email, user_login.userlogin_id AS user_login_userlogin_id,
user_info.fname AS user_info_fname, user_info.lname AS user_info_lname,
user_friend.status AS user_friend_status FROM user_login LEFT OUTER JOIN 
user_info ON user_login.userlogin_id = user_info.userlogin_id LEFT OUTER JOIN 
user_friend ON 

user_login.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_from_userlogin_id OR 
user_login.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_to_userlogin_id 

WHERE user_login.email = %(email_1)s
```

How should I structure the sqlalchemy such that there will be () for **user_login.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_from_userlogin_id OR 
user_login.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_to_userlogin_id** for the last LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: You don't need parentheses around the join condition. You would only need them if you mix `AND` and `OR` conditions in the JOIN

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so LEFT OUTER JOIN 
user_friend ON user_login.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_from_userlogin_id OR user_login.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_to_userlogin_id is equivalent to LEFT OUTER JOIN user_friend on (user_info.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_from_userlogin_id OR user_info.userlogin_id = user_friend.send_to_userlogin_id )?

Comment: Yes, that's right.